# How to manage memory while feeding a model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with a tensorflow backend to solve an image classification problem. I had initially taken a naïve approach of loading all of the images from the files into an array which I passed to the Keras fit() function. This worked as long as I used thumbnails of the images, but I have lately decided to use the full size images.

No sooner had I tried this when I got the following error:

*2018-10-18 20:39:14.486023: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (mklcpu) ran out of memory trying to allocate 63.50GiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2018-10-18 20:39:14.490332: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:630] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 24, Chunks in use: 22. 6.0KiB allocated for chunks. 5.5KiB in use in bin. 2.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.*

This of course was hardly a surprise, because the images are over 1 MB apiece, and I have about 5000 of them.The question is what to do about this.

One possible naïve solution is simply to load the images in small numbers, and repeatedly call the fit () function with about, say, 10 images at a time. What I want to know is if Keras and Tensorflow can offer a better and more elegant solution to this problem. I am thinking essentially of a callback type function that would execute every time a batch is loaded, in which I would manually read the files into bitmaps to feed into the optimizer.

I don't need a detailed answer-if someone could just point me in a general way to the correct area of the documentation, I would appreciate that.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times before, the solution is to build a generator function that only loads a batch of images at a time, and to use fit_generator so keras calls it during training.

Answer (score 0):

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

This page has almost all of the information you need. I recommend reading all of it.